# Test classes deployment code coverage

Tags: apex, unit-test

If I am deploying test classes from sandbox to production, how does Salesforce calculate the code covergae?

**For example:**
If I have 5 classes with 5 test classes, should the overall average coverage be greater than 75? Or should each test class have at least 75 percent code coverage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you deploy with *Run All Tests*, then you only need 75% average across **all** classes (some individual classes may be less than 75%), and 1% coverage on all triggers. If you deploy with *Run Specified Tests*, then **each** class covered must individually meet or exceed 75% coverage. So, both statements in your question are true, depending on the mode you choose to deploy with.

Comment: Thanks sfdcfox. Your help for so many of us is extremely appreciable. Poeple like you share knowledge and help others grow. Thankuuuuu

Answer (score 1):

> Code coverage percentage is a calculation of the number of covered
>   lines divided by the sum of the number of covered lines and uncovered
>   lines. Only executable lines of code are included.

The complete reference guide can be found in the [Apex Developer Guide - Testing and Code Coverage](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_code_coverage_intro.htm)